# I can't log in with spring security, the password is always wrong

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I want to start the login, I always get the wrong password response and I don't get an error in the terminal of any kind, the problem is that I can't use spring boot and I'm completely sure that I enter the user I have registered, when I have used more recent spring versions I have not had any problem, this is my configuration I hope you can help me.

I feel like the error may be in the spring security settings in the xml, the truth is I have never configured the security from an xml, what could I say about this?

rest-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">



    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="mx.com.demo.ccas.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="mx.com.demo.ccas.controllers" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSourceOracleL"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName5}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseur5}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username5}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password5}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcDataSourceOracleL"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceOracleL" />
    </bean>


     <bean id="myUserDetailsService" 
        class="mx.com.demo.ccas.service.impl.LoginPropertiesService"> </bean>

    <bean id="LDAPAutentificacionService"
        class="mx.com.demo.ccas.service.LDAPAutentificacionService">
    </bean>


    <bean id="formularioService"
        class="mx.com.demo.ccas.service.impl.FormularioServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        class="mx.com.demo.ccas.service.impl.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName5=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.databaseur5=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
jdbc.username5=system
jdbc.password5=Admin123
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/start.jsp" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/formulario/getPoints/" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <!-- Gestión de login -->

        <!-- authentication-failure-url="/rest/autenticacion/Error2/" -->
        <form-login 
            login-page="/pages/login.jsp"
            default-target-url="/pages/start.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.jsp?error=2"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
            always-use-default-target="true" 
        />

        <session-management
            invalid-session-url="/pages/login.jsp?invalid">
            <concurrency-control
                expired-url="/pages/login.jsp?expired" max-sessions="1" />
            <!-- <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/pages/login.jsp"/> -->
        </session-management>

        <access-denied-handler
            error-page="/pages/403.jsp" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/pages/login.jsp?logout"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <csrf/>
    </http>


    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSourceOracleL"
          users-by-username-query= "select username,password,enabled from users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query= "select username, role from user_roles where username=?" 
         />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager >


</beans:beans>
```

login.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><%@page language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@page session="true"%>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <%
        String errorValidacion = "";
        String src = "";
        String showHide = "hidden";
    %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        localStorage.clear();
    </script>

    <title>JCDecaux</title>
    <link rel="shorcut icon" href="../imagenes/icono-mex.ico">


    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementById('username').focus();">

        <div class="limiter">
            <div class="container-login100 bg-login">
                <div class="wrap-login100">
                    <%
                        if ("0".equals(request.getParameter("error"))) {
                            errorValidacion = "LDAP connection error.";
                            showHide = "visible";
                        }
                        if ("2".equals(request.getParameter("error"))) {
                            errorValidacion = "Incorrect password.";
                            showHide = "visible";
                        }
                        if ("3".equals(request.getParameter("error"))) {
                            errorValidacion = "Wrong user.";
                            showHide = "visible";
                        }
                    %>
                    <form class="login100-form validate-form" role="form" id="loginForm"
                        action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />"
                        name="loginForm" method="POST">
                        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide"
                            style="height: 100px;" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="../imagenes/logo-DIF.png"
                                        class="img-fluid w-100 rounded-left" style="height: 70px;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="../imagenes/logo-DIF-azul.png"
                                        class="img-fluid w-100 rounded-left" style="height: 70px;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26"> Mi LOGIN </span>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input"
                            data-validate="Ingrese su usuario">
                            <input class="input100 loginColor" type="text" id="username" name="username">
                            <span class="focus-input100 loginColor" data-placeholder="Usuario"></span>
                        </div>
                        <!--  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12"> <input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input"
                            data-validate="Ingrese su contraseña">
                            <span class="btn-show-pass"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                            </span> <input class="input100 loginColor" type="password" id="password"
                                name="password"> <span class="focus-input100"
                                data-placeholder="Contraseña"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                                <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>

                                <button class="login100-form-btn btn btn-block btn-outline-primary" id="validar" type="submit">Start
                                    sesion</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" />

                        <hr>
                        <div style="visibility:<%=showHide%>">
                            <%=errorValidacion%>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put your values from property file directly into your dataSource bean value?

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="Admin123" />
```

Maybe an issue is with passing data from property file to your XML?

Comment: I have put it directly in the bean properties and it remains the same, if I configure the spring-segurity. xml with the following
<user-service> <user name ="bello" password="124" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /></user-service>
If I can log in